# Ошибка индекса: Индекс списка вне диапазона (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, массивы, vkontakte-api

```
elif response == 'хах' or response =='ахах' or response =='тестc':
     r = random.randint(1,3)
     answers = ['Смешно тебе?','Не смешно','Лол']
     send_message(vk_session, 'user_id', event.user_id, message=answers[r])
```

некоторое время работает а потом вываливается в ошибку[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

3-4 раза работает и отваливается.. иногда даже и два раза не отрабатывает.

подскажите плиз что не так может быть?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У вас происходит выход за пределы массива, т.к. индексация его начинается с 0, а `randint(1,3)` возвращает значения от 1 до 3 включительно, т.е. первый элемент (индекс 0) вообще не появится, а время от времени будет возвращаться индекс 3 и та ошибка.

Лучше использовать специальный метод [random.choice](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choice) для возврата случайного элемента из коллекции:

```
answers = ['Смешно тебе?','Не смешно','Лол']
send_message(vk_session, 'user_id', event.user_id, message=random.choice(answers))
```

Comment: благодарю! проверю как это работает:)

Comment: использовал Вашу конструкцию:) работает как часы!

Comment: @ИгнатийШиленин, рад что помогло :)

Answer (score 3):

Индексация списков начинается с нуля.

```
r = random.randint(3)
```

Answer (score 3):

Индексация списков начинается с нуля.

Ваш список `answers = ['Смешно тебе?','Не смешно','Лол']`  имеет индексы от 0 до 2, а рандом дает случайное число от 1 до 3.

По этому при обращению к вашему списку `message=answers[r]` вы иногда обращаетесь к несуществующему элементу с номером 3.

По этому измените ваш рандом на `r = random.randint(0, 2)`

PS
Для поиска подобных проблем вам всегда может помочь обычный вывод через `print` в консоль значений ваших переменных